# how to match a pattern but get different value

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

in .htaccess I need to match a pattern (possible pattern, it may not exist) but get a different value to $1

Example urls:

```
http://www.example.com/rest-of-the-url
http://www.example.com/en/rest-of-the-url
http://www.example.com/fr/rest-of-the-url
http://www.example.com/it/rest-of-the-url
```

**en/ fr/ it/** parts may or may not exist

I use this pattern to match language in a form **en fr** ...

```
^([a-z]{2})?other patterns here$
```

which is ok and I get the language part to **$1**. But the problem is when there is no language part, then **$1** becomes **re** from **rest-of-the-url**

If I use this pattern

```
^([a-z]{2}\/)?other patterns here$
```

with this pattern I can get languages properly whether they exist or not to **$1** but in a form like **en/** fr/ ... which I don't want trailing **/**

Is it possible to match like in the second example and get the value like the first one?

PS: Yes it's very easy to clean trailing **/** in php but I'm asking if it's possible to do this in htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is very much **possible** to do that in .htaccess. Trick is to use non-capturing regex groups using `?:`. Use following regex e.g.:

```
^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?(.+)$
```

Using above regex `$1` will have `en` or `fr` without trailing slash `/` and `$2` will have rest of URI.